# Restriction of exponential function is homeomorphism .

Tags: general-topology

The exponential function $f:\left(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\to \mathbb{S}^1\backslash\{ -1\}$ defined by $f(x)=e^{2\pi i t}$ is a homeomorphism.

I have already proved that $f$ is continuous and injective. But can't show the inverse is continuous or that $f$ is onto.

Can anybody help for continuity of inverse part? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For surjectivity use the Euler's formula: $e^{ix}=\cos x +i\sin x$ together with complex argument. For continuous inverse show that $f$ is open.

Comment: For homomorphism one has structure on the sets.  For part of the complex unit circle this could be complex multiplication, but what is the structure of $(-1/2, 1/2$? $a+b\text{ mod }1$ does not work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Dear freakish, I can't see the proof of continuous inverse. If U is an open sunset then what would be it's inverse? If possible, Please give details answers. Thanks.

Comment: @GolamBiswas show that if $U\subseteq (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is open then $f(U)$ is open in $S^1\backslash\{-1\}$. This can be done by analyzing sequences convergent to some point in $f(U)$ and showing that almost all elements of such sequence have to be in $f(U)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential function is $e : \mathbb R \to S^1, e(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. It is well-known that this a continuous surjection with the property
$$e(s) = e(t) \Leftrightarrow s - t \in \mathbb Z .\tag{1}$$

This implies that $e$ maps $(- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2]$ bijectively onto $S^1$. Since $e(\frac 1 2) = -1$, we see that $e$ maps $(- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2)$ bijectively onto $S = S^1 \setminus \{-1\}$. This shows that the restriction $f: (- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2) \to S$ of $e$ is a continuous bijection.

$f$ is an open map (and thus a homeomorphism):

Let $U \subset (- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2) $ be open. Then $C  = [- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2] \setminus U$ is compact, hence $e(C)$ is a compact subset of $S^1$ and $V = S^1 \setminus e(C)$ is open in $S^1$. Clearly $V \subset S$ since $\frac 1 2 \in C$ which implies $-1 \in e(C)$. Thus $V = S \cap V$ is open in $S$. We have $[- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2] = C \cup U$ and therefore $S^1 = e([- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2]) = e(C) \cup e(U)$. The sets $e(C)$ and $e(U)$ are disjoint because points $s \in C$ and $t \in U$ cannot have the same image under $e$ (recall that $- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2$ are the only two points of $[- \frac 1 2, \frac 1 2]$ mapped by $e$ to the same point of $S^1$, and **both of them** belong to $C$ whereas $t \notin C$).  We conclude $f(U) = e(U) = S^1 \setminus e(C) = V$.

Comment: Dear @Paul Frost , thank you so much .Can you please explain why e maps (-1/2,1/2] bijectively onto S^1 ?please answer sir.

Comment: @GolamBiswas It is injective because for $s, t \in (-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2]$ we have $\lvert s - t \rvert < 1$, thus $s - t \notin \mathbb Z$, thus $e(s) \ne e(t)$ by $(1)$. It is surjective because for $z \in S^1$ we have $z = e(t)$ for some $t \in \mathbb R$. Now let $k \in \mathbb Z$ be the biggest integer $\le t$. Then $t' = t- k \in [0,1)$ and $e(t') = e(t) = z$ by $(1)$. If $t' \in [0,\frac 1 2]$, we have found $t'  \in (-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2]$ with $e(t') = t$. If $t' \in (\frac 1 2,1)$, we set $t'' = t' -1 \in  (-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2]$ and get $e(t'') = z$.

Comment: Dear @Paul Froust , Special thanks to you .Your answers is very helpful .

Comment: But can we use epsilon-delta defination to prove f is continous ?This is a question from algebraic topology ..so in topology as far i know epsilon _delta defination is Not  true in general.Again since Cosx ,sinx are continous therefore f(x)=(cosx ,sinx) is continous by Euler's formula . Again i seen that in Path lifting property , all authors were used epsilon delta defination .

Comment: @GolamBiswas Yes, you can prove the continuity of $\sin$ and $\cos$ by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition (because they are functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ in which case we may use the methods from elementary calculus). This also works for maps between arbitrary metric spaces, but for general topological spaces you have to consider open sets.

Comment: thanks again. I done continuity by epsilon-delta definition.

Comment: @ Faul Forst, can you please tell me how to prove continuity by open set. I thought if we take a open set from unit circle then it's inverse image under exponential map is union of disjoint open interval of R, that is union of disjoint open intervals of the form (n-1/2 , n+1/2). Am I right sir? Please give your responses.

Comment: @GolamBiswas In my opinion there are two main approaches to prove the continuity of $f$. Either consider the two real functions $\sin, \cos$ or the complex function $e^{2\pi it}$. These are studied in elementary calculus resp. complex analysis. Usually one uses an $\epsilon$-$\delta$-proof based on the representation of the above functions by power series. I do not see that a proof considering inverse images of open subsets of $S^1$ would be easier. Anyway, perhaps you should ask a new question concerning an "elegant" proof of the continuity of $f$.